# Randomization of patterns in a dataset

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, random, machine-learning, dataset

I am pretty new to the ML world and I am trying to randomize the datasets `X_Train`, `Y_Train` to later build minibatches from them. The randomization of `X_Train` works fine, but that of `Y_Train` keeps giving me traceback:

> can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

```
import numpy as np
import math

def create_datasets():
   dataset = np.genfromtxt('winequality-white.csv', delimiter=';')
   dataset = dataset[1:,:]
   X_Test=dataset[:64,:-1]
   X_Train=dataset[64:,:-1]
   m = X_Train.shape[0]
   Y_Test=dataset[:64,-1:]
   Y_Train=dataset[64:,-1:].reshape(m,1)

   return X_Train, Y_Train, X_Test, Y_Test, m

def shuffling(X_Train,Y_Train,m,minibatch_size):
   permutation=list(np.random.permutation(m))
   shuffled_X=X_Train[permutation,:].T
   shuffled_Y=Y_Train[permutation,:]
   n_comp_minibatches=math.floor(m/minibatch_size)    #Total n. of minibatches with 64 elements
   minibatches=[]
```

Is anybody able to tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine to me. Here's a complete version:

```
def shuffling(X_Train, Y_Train, m, minibatch_size):
    permutation = list(np.random.permutation(m))
    shuffled_X = X_Train[permutation, :]
    shuffled_Y = Y_Train[permutation, :]
    n_comp_minibatches = math.floor(m / minibatch_size)
    minibatches = [(shuffled_X[i*minibatch_size:(i+1)*minibatch_size],
                    shuffled_Y[i*minibatch_size:(i+1)*minibatch_size])
                   for i in range(n_comp_minibatches)]
    return minibatches
```

If you want to include the last incomplete mini-batch as well, simply use `n_comp_minibatches + 1` in the list comprehension. Also it's usually more convenient to work with `[rows, features]` data rather than `[features, data]`, that's why I skipped the transposition, but it's up to you.

Comment: Actually I've been adopting the convention [features, data] only because the Professor suggested it, but I'm flexible in switching to the other when necessary. However, there seems to be a problem because it always throws that error when it tries to permute Y_(Train, Test) elements! As soon as I comment permutations out of minibatches creation, the error vanishes

Comment: @Sim1bet what is your python and numpy? I've tested this code, it works

Comment: Currently running Python 3.6.1 and Numpy 1.12.1 of the Anaconda distribution.
I run your code and it works. I suspect the the error was somewhere within the initialization of the session for Tensorflow because the shuffling function works when implemented in a non Tensorflow-mediated algorithm. Anyway, thanks for the support! (I'll upvote you as soon as I reach 15-reputation)